# android textview how to code on keep pressing

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview that has an image, i want to change that image as long as the user keep pressing the textview and when he finish clicking i want to return the old image , how please?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_simple_list_item_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_food_profile_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/favorite"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_food_profile_addToBasket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/add_to_basket"
        android:text="@string/tv_addToBasket"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### java

```
TextView tv_addToBasket;
tv_addToBasket = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_food_profile_addToBasket);
```

#### Note:

I can change the image, i am just asking about what listener (or something else) i should use,

thank you very much

#### edit

```
tv_addToBasket.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a textview that has an image, i want to change that image as
>   long as the user keep pressing the textview and when he finish
>   clicking i want to return the old image , how please?

So first idea is to use `OnTouchListener()` and when you touch on `TextView` just call `setPressed()` method and set it to **true** and while is true so change background.

When you touch out so call again `setPressed()` method and set it to **false** and change background.

Comment: when i did this `tv_addToBasket.onTouchEvent` there is no `new onTouchListener` whey?

Comment: you need to do it as `tv_addToBasket.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouch...);`

Comment: I added it , check my edited question, but i don't know what to do inside the `onTouch` function

Comment: so you need to use MotionEvent so if `(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.TYPE) { // do your work }`

Comment: there is no motionEvent.Type

Comment: oh, there you have types of events.. motion_down, motion_up etc.

Comment: would you check my new question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909892/android-textview-how-to-code-on-keep-pressing/14909958#14909958

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible solutions to your problem. First of all set your `android:clickable="true"` attribute, then use a selector or handle by code

1) Use a selector for the drawable you would like to change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable_here" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable_here" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

2) Use a handler for your text view

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_food_profile_addToBasket);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // change image per code
    }
})
```